# Cloud Firestore not writing data consistently (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have TextFormField's within a Stateful widget, with controllers and an onPress to save data as a document in Cloud Firestore. Roughly say 1 in 4 times when I fill the form fields and save, it shows the data in the firestore fields. For the other 3, every 'type' returns 'null'. How would one go about fixing this?

```
onPressed: () async {
          //save data to firebase

          await db.collection("Contacts").add(
            {
              'Name': widget.contact.name,
              'PhoneNumber': widget.contact.phoneNumber,
              'Location': widget.contact.location,
              'Birthday': widget.contact.birthday,
              'Notes': widget.contact.notes
            },
          );
          widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
          widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
          widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
          widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
          widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second");
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched the controllers and db logic around